# How many patterns?

Tags: combinatorics

You probably have seen #patterns# in android devices witch working like passwords.

[image: some patterns]

My question is how many patterns can we draw in a 3*3 net and then how many in a m*n?

assumptions:

-a pattern can be just a dot

-the direction is important and makes diffrent patterns

-you can't connect any two dots directly!

Comment: if you wanna break into someone's phone, you could just look at the fingermarks on the screen :)

Comment: See if [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459234) helps, or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252027).

Comment: So you basically have no constraints on the graphs then?

Comment: @Chinny84 nothing but what is on mobiles

Answer (score 1):

Let us mark all the points as shown.  C - Corner, M - Middle, T- Center.

Each C can reach 2 M OR 1 T, Each M can reach 2 M, 2 C OR 1 T, T can reach 4 C OR 4 M. 
[image]

Step 1: 1 step password is allowed, so there are 9 ways.

Step 2: Out of the 9 ways of step 1, there are 4 Cs, 4 Ms and 1 T.  Each of the 4 Cs can reach 2 Ms or 1 T, each of the 4 Ms can reach 2 Ms, 2 Cs or 1 T, 1 T can reach 4 Cs or 4 Ms.  So there are $12+20+8=40$ ways to complete step 2.

[image]

Step 3: Collect all the Cs and Ms together.  Now the choice of Ms for Ms will be reduced by 1, since we can't go back to from where we came.
So $18+32+16=66$ ways to complete step 3.
[image]

Same way

$\underline{\text{Step 4}:} 62 $ways$\hspace{50 pt}$
$\underline{\text{Step 5}:} 62 $ways$\hspace{50 pt}$
$\underline{\text{Step 6}:} 62 $ways$\hspace{50 pt}$

$\underline{\text{Step 7}:} 62 $ways$\hspace{50 pt}$
$\underline{\text{Step 8}:} 62 $ways$\hspace{50 pt}$
$\underline{\text{Step 9}:} 62 $ways$\hspace{50 pt}$

So TOTAL number of combinations=No of ways of step 1+No of ways of step (1*2)+No of ways of step (1*2*3) +...+ No of ways of step (1*2*3*...*9)

NOTE: I was not aware about what is mentioned in the previous answer and comments that we can reach any point from any point.

Comment: Wow! Just Brilliant..+1

Comment: @Vikram, your solution seems to contain paths with loops, say ABA or ABCA (for any A, B, C points which are accessible form one anther). Is this kind of path 'what is on mobiles', as OP requested?

Comment: @CiaPan, to avoid that form step 3 onward I have reduced 1 from the total options available.

Comment: @Vikram Ah, yes, thanks.

Comment: @Vikram I think there is a little bug: each C can reach  **4**  M  and each M can reach  **4**  C

Comment: @SayedMahdi, yes, u r right, that will change the total number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an $m \times n$ grid of dots and each stroke can go from any dot to any other dot, the number of patterns of $k$ strokes is $mn (mn-1)^k$.

Comment: you can't connect any two dots directly!

Comment: @SayedMahdi Are you sure one 'can't connect any two dots directly'? AFAIK you can go from any corner to another corner and not touch any mid-dot... Even if your fingers are not slim enough to pass between dots without touching them, you can use two fingers: put one finger on dot A, next the other finger on dot B, then lift the first finger from A - a device recognizes A-to-B pass, even though it was rather a jump instead of a stroke. I used this trick for a skew line in a pattern similar to the one in the last row, second column of your image.

Comment: @CiaPan I don't know but if what you said is true this counting is so easy let's see what if we can't connect any two dots directly!

Comment: @CiaPan, I tried it, you can not jump a dot.  If you select top one point and bottom one point, device counts the middle point.